# Codeigniter: Can edit form and insert form use the same validation?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

This is my function validation for insert article. But when I work with edit article also have form validation and with same condition. So I would like to use only one function validation instead of copy and paste.

```
 function article_validation()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Article Name','required|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('content','Article body','required|trim|xss_clean');
        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $this->load->model('article');
            $this->article->insert_article();
            redirect('article');

        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('page/insert');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an `is_valid` method in you `controller`, call it anywhere in your `controller`, just make your `is_valid` function private to avoid being routed.

```
Class Articles {
       private function is_valid(){
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Article Name','required|trim|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('content','Article body','required|trim|xss_clean');

            return $this->form_validation->run();
       }

       public function create_article()
       {
           if($this->is_valid()){
                //save in DB
           }
       }

       public function edit_article($id)
       {
           if($this->is_valid()){
                //save in DB
           }
       }
}
```